# Как повесить два сайта на один внешний IP?

Tags: веб-программирование, nginx, ip, веб-сервер

У машины есть внутренний IP и внешний IP (который переадресует на внутренний).

файл конфигурации `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` настроен так:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  192.168.12.12;
    root /home/ivanov/secure;
    # passenger_enabled on;

    location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;

    }
```

Для второго сайта я так понимаю нужно задать второй блок `server` в `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`

```
server {
    listen       55;
    server_name  192.168.12.12;
    root /home/ivanov/hair;
    # passenger_enabled on;

    location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;

    }
```

Но это все равно не выходит. В чем ошибка?
Вообще, срабатывает только secure, даже если я просто в первом блоке пропишу `root /home/ivanov/hair;`, то сайт не заработает. В чем тут дело?

Comment: Для второго сайта вы открываете именно `http://192.168.12.12:55/`? Ни на каком другом адресе он работать не будет, потому что в настройках прописан ровно такой

Comment: *с которого я настроил переадресацию на внутренний 192.168.12.12* — вы настроили переадресацию 80-го порта с внешнего ip на 80-й порт на внутренний. добавьте и переадресацию какого-нибудь порта с внешнего ip на 55-й порт на внутренний.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> я настроил переадресацию на внутренний

вы настроили переадресацию 80-го порта с внешнего ip-адреса на 80-й порт на внутренний ip-адрес.

теперь **там же** добавьте и переадресацию какого-нибудь другого порта с внешнего ip-адреса на 55-й порт на тот же внутренний ip-адрес.